# problem saving/ retrieving custom meta with wp alchemy metabox

Tags: customization, metabox, wpalchemy

I am using WPalchemy metabox class to add a extra meta field to the pages editor which will allow me to attach galleries to pages. I use the class:

```
$gallery_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array(
    'id' => '_gallery_meta',
    'title' => 'Gallery',
    'template' => STYLESHEETPATH . '/inc/custom/gallery_meta.php',
    'types' => array('post', 'page', 'events'),
    'priority' => 'high',    
    'lock' => WPALCHEMY_LOCK_AFTER_POST_TITLE
));
```

Here's my gallery_meta.php:

```
<div class="my_meta_control">
 <?php $metabox->the_field('attachedGallery'); ?>
    <label>Attached gallery </label>
    <p>

        <select name="<?php $metabox->the_name(); ?>">
        <option value="0">select gallery</option>       
        <?php
        //global $post;
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'galleries', 'posts_per_page' => 999, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
            <option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php echo $mb->is_value(get_the_ID())? $selected :''; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </select>
    </p>

</div>
```

The input field appears in the WP admin for posts/ pages and events. When I save the value it seems it doesn't save. I checked the mysql db and for this particular page I am testing there is a row with:
meta_key `_gallery_meta`
meta_value `a:1:{s:16:"attached-gallery";s:3:"109";}`

I can't retrieve the value of the $gallery_metabox or make the select element mark the option as selected though. Can anyone help?

Comment: Review Note: Close voted based on the answer given.

Answer (score 1):

This was not WPAlchemy problem. It was a matter of running a custom query. Some vital information about current post, like ID of the post I was editing got lost.

Comment: How did you solve this?